# Web Browser for Android 12 with access to files on SD card

Tags: android, javascript, web-browser

I am looking for an application on Android 12 which can browse HTML files on the local storage and run Javascript.

This request can seem a bit stupid as any decent browser (Chrome, Firefox, Opera, ... ) should be able to do that with a `file:///storage/...` URL, however, since Android 11, access to the whole SD card has been forbidden, unless special authorizations are requested  by the app. On previous Android versions, I could do this without any problem.

I have tried something like 10 different browsers, none of them allow access to the SD card. There is also countless "HTML local viewers" I could try, but, here again, either they do not have the necessary permissions or they are too basic to run Javascript.

I also tried to force permissions since my phone is rooted via special debug commands (`adb`, `pm`, ...), but this stupid problem seems hopeless !

Comment: As far as I know web browsers have disabled file protocol some time before scoped storage was introduced.

Comment: Have you considered running a small-footprint server on the phone itself? Not sure if this will work, but if a) this is a valid option for you and b) there is such a server that can access the local storage, then you might be able to open the files from `http[s]://<local-ip>/`

Comment: @Amin I tried with "HTTP File Server (+WebDAV)" from "slowscript" and this actually works with Android 12 after spending a few moment to configure the setup and many tries. Thanks.